# Typescript + React: Getting Property Does Not Exist on Interface, when it does

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Working with an API that I have matched the properties to an interface using an auto tool:

```
export interface Root {
  stationId: number;
  results: Results;
}
```

For brevity, I won't include the additional results interfaces. I then send the fetch request to get the data, and I am now trying to display this in my JSX elements.

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState<Root[]>([]);

  function getTimes(): Promise<Root[]> {
    return fetch("http://localhost:3000/times/9117")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => data as Root[]);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getTimes().then((item) => setData(item));
  }, []);

  console.log(data);
  return <div className="App">{data.stationId}</div>;
}

export default App;
```

The API response looks something like this:

```
{
  "stationId": 9117,
  "results": {
    "LatestUpdate": "2023-02-09T09:59:29",
    "DataAge": 63,
    "Metros": [
      {...}
     ]
}
```

I receive an error that says:

> Property 'stationId' does not exist on type 'Root[]'

I am not sure how this is possible since when I hover over stationId it says `(property) Root.stationId: number`. Any ideas on why it is not recognizing this as a property of the interface? Also, how would I read the properties in the API response like `data.results.Metros`?

I have tried `console.log(data)`, and it shows the object as expected. I also have tried `JSON.stringfy(data)` which also works and shows on the page. I am not sure why I can't just read this property and show it in an element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a misalignment between the data you are getting, which is an object, and how you defined your type, which is an array of that object. You could do so instead:

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState<Root | null>(null);

  function getTimes(): Promise<Root> {
    return fetch("http://localhost:3000/times/9117")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => data as Root);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getTimes().then((item) => setData(item));
  }, []);

  return <div className="App">{data?.stationId}</div>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: That did it thanks! I had a feeling it was something to do with it. I'm curious why data? needs to be optional here though.

Comment: Glad it did :) The `?` is because the initial value is null. It’s a JavaScript functionality: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining